# Bluetooth and BLE profiles

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

There are many Bluetooth profiles specified, but no clear information as to which underlying protocol they use, i.e. Bluetooth Classic or Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE).

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles

Are profiles specific to either Bluetooth Classic or BLE or compatible with both?
Is there a list of compatibility?

Many thanks

Comment: as stated on Wikipedia, BLE uses a special set of profiles. Only ATT and GATT are listed as basic profiles in the article. Have a look at this list for BLE profiles on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy#Applications) or the official site (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/)